# Service Stack Markdown

Tags: servicestack

Does anyone know how to use an enum's ToString method in Service Stack Markdown? I've got a property on my Message object called Status that's an enumeration with 4 values. In markdown I'm doing this...

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Messages) {
<tr>
  <td>@m.Id</td>
  <td>@m.Endpoint</td>
  <td>@m.Status</td>
</tr>
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying the Enum can't be passed in to String.ToString(Object). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily ideal but I solved this by adding a CustomerMarkdownViewBase with a method for returning an object's to String method.

```
Public Class CustomMarkdownViewBase
    Inherits MarkdownViewBase

    Public Function ObjectToString(o As Object) As String
        Return o.ToString
    End Function

End Class
```

Then in the markdown I do the following.

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Messages) {
<tr>
  <td>@m.Id</td>
  <td>@m.Endpoint</td>
  <td>@ObjectToString(@m.Status)</td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try service stack's enum extension `ToDescription()`

```
<td>@m.Status.ToDescription()</td>
```